# Which is the correct algorithm while checksumming a portion of code?

Tags: cryptography, hash, integrity

As part of my research, I came across a technique in a paper which applies checksumming on a portion of code. I want to implement it. 
[Here](https://www.cerias.purdue.edu/assets/pdf/bibtex_archive/2001-49.pdf) is the research paper which talks about the checksumming guard techqniue.

Here is the guard template:

```
guard:
      add ebp, -checksum
      mov eax, client_addr

for:
      cmp eax, client_end
      jg end
      mov ebx, dword[eax]
      add ebp, ebx
      add eax, 4
      jmp for
end:
```

As you can see, here just addition of opcodes is performed. Can someone suggest a stronger method of doing it?  Also, someone suggested Message Authentication techniques like MACs, digital signatures, authentic encryption? What would be the best method?

Comment: What purpose is this supposed to serve? Protection from code manipulation? When one can patch your business logic, what stops them from also patching your guard routines?

Comment: Yes, protection from code manipulation is what it intends to. Actually, I am trying to implement this paper and I am a student, so please don't go into the practicality of it. Also, I am also looking into obfuscation of the guard code to make it harder for the attacker to modify it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we can not "suggest a stronger method" without "going into the practicality". When the whole concept is broken by design, using stronger algorithms would just be snakeoil.

Comment: See, obfuscating the guard code would make it harder for the person to identify that some protection is being applied and therefore if the person changes the code to be protected, the guard code will detect an error. I know the system is not fullproof.

Comment: @ak0817 I suggest you read into [Kerckhoffs's principle / Shannon's maxim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle) and [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: @Polynomial Thank you for your help. I understand that obfuscation is not security but it does make it harder for the attacker to understand what's going on. And can you suggest which method to use - cryptographic hash, MAC, or digital signature, considering the fact that the code I want to protect is a small one(100-200 lines) and therefore if I use a complicated hash or technique, the runtime would blow up.

Comment: @ak0817 If a post answered your question, please mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand that this is security through obscurity and provides no meaningful level of integrity against an adversary who is attempting to modify your code in memory. For this to be effective in any way, the CPU's internal hardware would have to be the one verifying the checksum, allowing modified code to simply refuse to execute. If the check is entirely in software, an attacker could quite trivially modify the checksum itself to match the modified code before it is executed.

With that said, the method to use would be a hash of some sort. There are three types of hashes:

- **Checksums** involve the addition of a numerical representation of each component of the data, sometimes multiplied by a weight factor. Checksums are extremely fast, but are not cryptographically secure and can often miss modified data even under ideal circumstances.

  An example is [Fletcher-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum).
- **Cyclic Redundancy Checks** use the remainder of polynomial division of the contents as a digest. The polynomial is carefully selected to increase the chance of detecting modification. They are generally very fast, but a malicious actor can trivially "break" them.

  An example is [CRC32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm).
- **Cryptographically secure hash functions** are much slower than the other options, but are designed to reduce the chance that two inputs with differing contents will resolve to the same digest, regardless of how they are generated. Non-collision-resistant functions can have any digest size. To be collision-resistant, they need larger digest size, such as 160 bits.

  A collision-resistant example is [SHA-256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). A non-collision-resistant example is [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash).

Given that you are only writing a proof of concept, you should use a simple and fast checksum or CRC. A proper implementation would use custom hardware verifying a cryptographically secure hash such as SHA-256 as part of a digitally-signed hash tree. If you have access to hardware with [SSE4.2](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/8/b/8/D9156103.pdf) (see page 61), you can use a hardware-accelerated implementation of CRC32c (using polynomial `0x11EDC6F41`). This allows a digest to be generated using one instruction for every QWORD of data to be processed, using the `crc32q` instruction. Otherwise, you would want to use a very fast and extremely simple checksum such as CrapWow or [Murmur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash). It will suffice for a proof-of-concept.